# Using repetitive "and" or "or" to relate sentences

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-request, conjunctions

It seems I have problem in using "and". I don't know its proper usage and sometimes my sentences get too long with many "and" between. (however here I used it deliberately)

for example I want to say:

> We avoid using absolute paths **and** rely more on the relative paths and the node attributes to locate an anchor node

Was my usage of "and" natural in the sentence above?

How can I rearrange such sentences and say less "and"?

and

Sometimes I have the problem with "or" too

> A context can starts from an anchor node **and** expand to its descendants
>   **or** its following nodes **or** it can include the parent and ancestors of a
>   node

How can I say it with less "and" and "or"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first sentence is correct and doesn't sound unnatural. My only suggestion is to remove 'the' before 'node'.

> We avoid using absolute paths and rely more on the relative paths and node attributes to locate an anchor node.

Generally you want to avoid using 'or' multiple times in a sentence. To improve your second sentence, you might say:

> A context can start from an anchor node and expand to its descendants, its following nodes or it can include the parent and ancestors of a node.

Or as Damkerng T. suggested you could split the second sentence into two sentences.

> A context can start from an anchor node and expand to its descendants or following nodes. It can also include the parent and ancestors of a node.

Comment: +1 I'd like to suggest another alternative for #2: *A context can start from an anchor node and expand to its descendants and its following nodes. It can also include the node's parent and ancestors.*

Comment: @DamkerngT. I think splitting it into two sentences makes it clearer. I'll update my answer.