# The ways to relate two sentences

Tags: sentence-construction, conjunctions

I asked a [related question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/59313/using-repetitive-and-or-or-to-relate-sentences) about excessive use of "and" or "or" to relate sentences. Here I would like to make it more general and ask for alternatives which can be used to relate sentences.

For example, I have the following construction:

> Such anchors are less affected by the modifications and revisions in the layout **and** they are less tailored to a specific website template.

I thought how can I remove the "and" and use other relations. Then I thought of these sentences:

- Such anchors are less affected by the modifications and revisions in the layout. **At the same time**, they are less tailored to a specific website template.
- Such anchors are less affected by the modifications and revisions in the layout, **meanwhile**, they are less tailored to a specific website template.
- Such anchors are less affected by the modifications and revisions in the layout. **Moreover**, they are less tailored to a specific website template.

....

First, I would like to know if my constructions are OK?

Second, to ask for some general rules for relating sentences which can be used in replace of "and".

Answer (score 1):

Really the first question is whether any conjunction is needed at all.  If 'and' does a good enough job to convey your meaning, then it may well be that nothing is required--or desired.  Needless verbosity is best avoided.

Only a need to convey additional detail about the relationship between the two sentences would call for the inclusion of any of your proposed alternatives.  'At the same time' and 'meanwhile' emphasize concurrence--often in the context of two things which seem to contradict each other.  'Moreover' is like 'furthermore' or 'additionally' and prepares the reader for something that is in some way further supporting a point already made.